# Principle of inclusion and exclusion with three sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

> Consider a ground set $U$ and let $A$,$B$, and $C$ be subsets of $U$ such that
>
> $$\vert U = 110 \vert, \vert A \vert = 36, \vert B \vert = 25, 
> \vert C \vert = 47, \vert A \cup B \cup C \vert = 90.$$
>
> In no element belongs to exactly two of the three subsets, what is the number of elements in the complement of $A\cap B \cap C$?

My answer was:

Since $\vert A\cup B \cup C \vert = \vert A \vert + \vert B \vert + \vert C \vert - \vert A \cap C \vert - \vert A \cap B \vert - \vert B \cap C \vert + \vert A \cap B \cap C \vert$ that means

$90 = 36 + 25 + 47 - 0 - 0 - 0 + \vert A \cap B \cap C \vert$

$90 = 36 + 25 + 47 - \vert A \cap B \cap C \vert$

$18 = \vert A \cap B \cap C \vert$

Thus $\vert U \vert - \vert A \cap B \cap C \vert = 110 - 18 = 92$

But the answer given is $101$.

And in looking at the answer there is a $2$ in front of the intersection of the three sets in the inclusion exclusion equation... that is, the answer displays

$90 = 36 + 25 + 47 - 2\vert A \cap B \cap C \vert$

which solves to

$9 = \vert A \cap B \cap C \vert$

and then

$\vert U \vert - \vert A \cap B \cap C \vert = 110 - 9 = 101$

Can someone help explain this discrepancy? I'm unfamiliar with this principle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> no element belongs to exactly two of the three subsets

Hint: this implies that any element which belongs to *two* subsets, must also belong to the third. So for example $|A \cap B| = |A \cap B \cap C|$.